# c#: assigning a .tsv file to a string[,] array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, csv, indexing

I'm looking to write a `.tsv` file into a `string[,]` array using ReadAllLines and subsequent for loops but I'm running into a lot of null exceptions and array bounds issues. The reason I'm going this route is because some other methods have proved too complicated for me to resolve.
 Below is the code I'm working with:

```
    string[] words;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        words = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"file.tsv");
        int k = words.Count();

        string[] count = words[1].Split(' ');
        int k2 = count.Count();

        string [,] wordsNew = new string[k, k2];

        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        { 
            string[] temp = words[i].Split(' ');

            for (int j = 0; j < k2; j++)
            {
                wordsNew[i, j] = temp[j];
            }
        }
    }
```

Regardless of little changes I make to where and how I assign `wordsNew`, I keep running into either null exception or index out of bounds errors. Anyone see any problems or have simpler solutions to this?

I'm rather new to c# and coding in general so I may have already seen the answer in another post without realizing it. If that's the case, a link to any other relevant topics would be much appreciated!